# C# json serialization - How to add name to object in list?

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> ItemsOrders
}

public class Item
{
    public string ItemID
    public decimal ItemPrice
}
```

When serialize it to XML - received named  array

```
<PurchaseOrder>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <ItemID>aaa111</ItemID>
            <ItemPrice>34.22</ItemPrice>
        <Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemID>bbb222</ItemID>
            <ItemPrice>2.89</ItemPrice>
        <Item>
    </Items>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

But when serialize it to JSON - received not named array

```
{
    "ItemsOrders": [{
        "ItemID": "aaa111",
        "ItemPrice": 34.22
    }, {
        "ItemID": "bbb222",
        "ItemPrice": 2.89
    }]
}
```

How can I add name Item for json array?

Comment: Your array property does have a name; it is `ItemsOrders`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do this:

```
{
  "ItemsOrders": 
  [
    {
      Item: 
      {
        "ItemID": "aaa111",
        "ItemPrice": 34.22
      }
    }, 
    {
      Item:
      {
        "ItemID": "bbb222",
        "ItemPrice": 2.89
      }
    }
  ]
}
```